# Force user to confirm signup CiviEvent

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Is it possible in some way to force users to confirm their signup before closing the window or leaving the page when they are on the confirmation page.

We've had to many persons missing doing that.

Comment: it helps if you tell us with version of CiviCRM (and Worpress I assume) you are using?

Comment: I am using CiviCRM 4.7.14 and Wordpress 4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

There is a little piece of javascript that kicks in on the contribution page to warn a visitor if they try to leave before submitting the form. It sounds like you want to have something like that for the confirmation page? I think that would be a useful feature. Forcing the user to do anything is going to be a non-starter of course ...

Alternatively you could also configure your contribution to skip the confirmation page.

Comment: I'll check that out!